# Работа с файлами Assembler через бибилиотеки Cи

Tags: функции, ассемблер, nasm

```
section .rodata
    file_in_name db "input.txt", 0
    file_out_name db "output.txt", 0
    arg_w db "w", 0
    arg_r db "r", 0
    f_d db "%d", 0
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp
    and esp, -16
    sub esp, 16
    mov eax, 1000
    mov dword[esp], eax
    call malloc
    mov dword [mas], eax; создание массива на 1000 эл-тов
    mov dword[esp], file_in_name
    mov dword[esp + 4], arg_r
    ;open file
    call fopen
    mov dword[pointer], eax ;сохранение указателя на файл для чтения
    xor esi, esi;counter
.L1:;read form file
    mov eax, dword[pointer]
    mov dword[esp], eax
    mov dword[esp + 4], f_d
    mov ebx, dword[mas + esi]
    mov dword[esp + 8], ebx
    call fscanf ;результат работы этой функции всегда -1. непонятно почему
    cmp eax, 1
    jne .end
    add esi, 4
    jmp .L1
.end:
    mov esp, ebp
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Вопрос: почему fscanf не читает?

Comment: У вас правильные пути? -1 это обычно `EOF`

Comment: файл лежит в папке с программой. считывание идет до конца файла.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена:

```
1.  file_in_name: db "input.txt", 0
    file_out_name: db "output.txt", 0
    arg_w: db "w", 0
    arg_r: db "r", 0
    f_d: db "%d", 0
```

2. Неправильно прописан путь к файлу.

Comment: Двоеточия не нужны. Какую конкретно проблему они решили у вас?